# How do I create a rounded image that contains another rounded image inside it?

Tags: android-studio

Create a profile picture that is round and has another circle merged with it.
Like the status picture on WhatsApp will give you a picture I want the same design:

[image: damaged donut]

Abstract: Put a rotated button inside the rotated image
And I want the layout to be SML and not shape drawable

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/image_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/story_photo"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:padding="6dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icccprofile_24dp" />
    <com.devlomi.circularstatusview.CircularStatusView
        android:id="@+id/circular_status_count"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        app:portion_color="@color/colorAccent"
        app:portion_spacing="4dp"
        app:portion_width="4dp"
        app:portions_count="8" />
    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/story_plus"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/circular_status_count"
        android:layout_marginTop="-27dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/circular_status_count"
        android:src="@drawable/add_circle_24"
        app:civ_border_color="@color/white"
        app:civ_border_overlay="true"
        app:civ_border_width="3dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```